# Quasicharacters of a complex algebraic torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, characters

Here is a characterization of continuous homomorphisms into $\mathbb C^{\ast}$ on a complex algebraic torus given by A. Borel in the Corvallis article *Automorphic L-functions*.

[image]

I don't understand where this characterization is coming from.

Consider the case where $T = \mathbb C^{\ast}$.  Since $\mathbb C^{\ast} = S^1 \times (0,\infty)$, a continuous homomorphism (quasicharacter) of $\mathbb C^{\ast}$ is a combination of a character $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$, which is of the form $z \mapsto z^m$ for a unique integer $m$, and a quasicharacter $(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb C^{\ast}$, which is of the form $x \mapsto x^s$ for a unique complex number $s$.  Therefore, for any quasicharacter $c: T \rightarrow \mathbb C^{\ast}$, there are unique $m \in \mathbb Z$ and $s \in \mathbb C^{\ast}$ such that

$$c(z) = (\frac{z}{|z|})^m |z|^s = z^m|z|^{s-m}$$

As long as $z \not\in (-\infty,0)$, we can write $|z|^{2t} = z^t \bar{z}^t$ for all complex numbers $t$, and so

$$c(z) = z^m z^{(s/2) - (m/2)} \bar z^{(s/2) - (m/2)} = z^{(s/2) + (m/2)} \bar z^{(s/2) - (m/2)}$$

where $(s/2) - (m/2)$ and $(s/2) + (m/2)$ differ by an integer.

If $z \in (-\infty,0)$, then I don't think this procedure works.  How do we account for $z$ negative, and generalize the arbitrary $T$?

Comment: I don't think $z^t$ makes sense for $z$ and $t$ complex, or, if it does, I don't think it has all of the properties we'd want from it. I don't think you should take $z^\mu$ literally for $\mu\in X_*(T)\otimes\mathbf{C}$. The claim for $T=\mathbf{C}^\times$ is exactly what you're saying, no more, no less -- you simply formally consider $s/2+m/2$ and $s/2-m/2$ as complexes and note that their difference is an integer.

Comment: In other words I'm saying that the *definition* of $z^\mu\overline{z}^\nu$ is $(z\overline{z})^\mu\times\overline{z}^{\nu-\mu}$